# How do I norm $5x+4$?

Tags: normed-spaces

So I would just simply write that like $\frac{5x+4}{\sqrt{41}}$. But solution says that correct answer is $\frac{5x+4}{146}*\sqrt{438}$. How do they get that?

Comment: What norm do you use?

Comment: How do you mean? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: They aren't equal!

Comment: There are different ways to compute a norm for $5x+4$. You need to specify which one you are supposed to use. (Your answer is correct for one somewhat, but not overly, natural choice of norm.) Otherwise one could only guess which one you should use based on the answer, but frankly that's a pain to do. So please check whatever source you are using for the definition of the norm. And tell us about it.

Comment: Vector normalization haha, but what kind of normalization should I use to get this? @quid

Comment: Where did you took the question and answer, or what's the problem about, that may help to see which is the correct norm you need to use

Comment: Once again there are different ways to compute a norm of a vector. Especially when the vector is a polynomial it is not that common to compute the norm as $\sqrt{a_0^2 +\dots +a_n^2 }$ where $a_i$ are the coeffcients of the polynomial but in one of several different ways some more natural than others. Check where the problem comes from  how you are supposed to compute the norm of a polynomial.

Comment: Even within polynomials, there's a whole lot of norms to choose from. (This is basically the subject of orthogonal polynomials, which has been studied a lot.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do they get that?

I'm guessing using the inner product

$$\langle g , h \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} g(x)h(x) \> dx$$

We see that

$$\|5x+4\| = \left(\int_{-1}^{1} (5x+4)^2 \> dx\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{146}{3}}$$

and therefore we normalize with

$$\sqrt{\frac{3}{146}} = \frac{\sqrt{438}}{146}$$

giving us the result your solution guide gives.

Comment: While I think this inner product is a plausible guess, it seems worth emphasizing that it isn't unique. For instance, there exists some $c$ such that the inner product $\langle g,h\rangle = c\cdot \int_0^1 g(x)h(x)\,dx$ again yields $\Vert 5x+4\Vert = \sqrt{146/3}$. (Other variations on this theme are possible.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Of course you are right. I thought "guess" indicated that it isn't unique, but if you think I should edit I will. I actually thought about formulating a completely ridiculous inner product choice that yields the solution answer, but decided against it.

Comment: I figured that's what you intended, but I thought it worth being explicit in a comment :)